# How to extract text from div class using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, class, webdriver

I am trying to create a bot to pay some bills automatically. The issue is I can't extract the amount(text) under div class. The error is element not found.
Used driver.find_element_by_xpath and WebDriverWait. Can you please indicate how to get the highlighted text-see the attached link? Thanks in advance.[Page_inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxlEB.jpg)

Comment: this is what I tried: amount = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="billPreferences"]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')))
        print('Your amount is: {}'.format(amount.text))
        return float(amount.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there was some issue with your xpath. Try below it should work:

```
amount = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[contains(@data-ng-bind-html,"vm.productList.totalAmt")]'))) 
print('Your amount is: {}'.format(amount.text)) 
return float(amount.text)
```

Comment: Rahul, when used your code got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")//div[@data-ng-bind-html="vm.productList.totalAmt"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")//div[@data-ng-bind-html="vm.productList.totalAmt"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Yes there was a syntax error. As forget to close ] in //div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[@data-ng-bind-html="vm.productList.totalAmt"] . I have updated please try now.

Comment: Unfortunately, is not finding it : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[starts-with(@class,"bill-summary-total")]//div[@data-ng-bind-html="vm.productList.totalAmt"]"}

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the link of your page as i am not sure id any typo error is there in xPath . Also can you updated one.

Comment: I can't share the link, i need first to log in and after to see the amount; the attached picture has the full path in it.

Comment: yes, now is working, I can get the amount; I think was a typo  error from my side. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help. Please up vote if it solves your issue. In turn it will help others and myself. Cheers!!!!

Comment: I did it, but the vote is not displayed; I do not have a reputation, hence the vote is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-ng-bind-html='vm.productList.totalAmt']").text`

I have written `XPath` on the basis of your attached image. Use list indexing to get a target div. For Example -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@data-ng-bind-html='vm.productList.totalAmt'])[1]").text`

Comment: @Pythonologist Wouldn't `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` and `[1]` together raise **TypeError 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: @Swaroop- when using your code, got this: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@data-ng-bind-html='vm.productList.totalAmt'])[1]"}

Comment: Use `time.sleep()` or `wait()` before finding the element. It will make sure that the element is present for use. And see, if your target element is in the `iframe`, then you have to change to that `iframe` first and then search for the element.

Comment: can you help me in finding the iframe and switch to the right one? I have already used WebDriverWait.